# Ordenar por id no AngularJS (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array, classificação

Tenho um objeto AngularJS:

```html
$scope.listaDoCarrinho = [0: {
        id: "55",
        setor: "alimento",
        foto: "Produtos/Produto (55).jpg",
        descr: "Espaguete Renata",
        de: 15,
        …
    }
    1: {
        id: "1000",
        setor: "biscoitos",
        foto: "Produtos/Produto (1000).jpg",
        descr: "Biscoito Pit-Stop",
        de: 3,
        …
    }
    2: {
        id: "3",
        setor: "higiene",
        foto: "Produtos/Produto (3).jpg",
        descr: "Bronzeador 200ml",
        de: 15,
        …
    }
];
```

Preciso mudar esta sequencia por id (3 -> 55 -> 1000). Existe uma maneira de fazê-lo sem que seja na hora do ng-repeat?

obs: o "-" (traço) no código é apenas para informar que o array tem mais propriedades insignificantes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `$filter` `orderBy`:

```
$scope.listaDoCarrinho = $filter('orderBy')($scope.listaDoCarrinho, 'id');
```

Mas veja bem, seu atributo `id` é uma `String`, portanto será ordenado alfabeticamente.

---

> [**`orderBy`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)
>
> Returns an array containing the items from the specified collection, ordered by a comparator function based on the values computed using the expression predicate.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna um array contendo os itens de uma coleção especificada, ordenados por uma função de comparação baseada nos valores computados usando a expressão predicativa.

Comment: Fazendo isso, o console informa "ReferenceError: filter is not defined".

Comment: @GuilhermeSilvadeOliveira tem que importar o $filter, fez isso?

Comment: Não, na verdade nunca usei o $filter... Vou pesquisar sobre como importá-lo.

Comment: Consegui. Para ordená-lo por ordem crescente, basta tirar os aspas do id, certo?

Comment: @GuilhermeSilvadeOliveira exato